# A menu with on page targets and page as target links?

Tags: javascript, scroll, menu, menuitem

I have  problem with a menu. The menu items is a combination of on page #sections and new pages target links. Now for the on page # targets i have a nice scroll animation. But in combo with the page target it doesn't work

I am able to jump to all the section and pages, but i like the scroll to work

This is the scroll javascript

```
  $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        //alert('lets scroll');
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: -160 + $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant HTML? And where is your `'easeInOutExpo'` easing defined?